How to handle foreground service notifications in React Native
I trying to use foreground services from https://www.npmjs.com/package/@supersami/rn-foreground-service and the problem I am facing is that, when I start the service, it creates a notification, but I cannot handle the event when I press the buttons on the notification or the main area of the notification.
The package I use https://www.npmjs.com/package/@supersami/rn-foreground-service
const start =async()=>{

  ReactNativeForegroundService.add_task(() => regularFunct(), {
    delay: 1000,
    onLoop: true,
    taskId: "taskid",
    onError: (e) => console.log(`Error logging:`, e),
  });
  //DeviceEventEmitter.addListener('notificationClickHandle',stop);
  ReactNativeForegroundService.eventListener(()=>stop);
  ReactNativeForegroundService.start({
    id: 1244,
    title: "Foreground Service",
    message: "We are live World",
    icon: "ic_launcher",
    button: true,
    buttonText: "Button",
    buttonOnPress: "notificationClickHandle", //this line i thought it will call the function but it does nothing
    mainOnPress:"notificationClickHandle", // same here
    setOnlyAlertOnce: true,
    color: "#000000",
    progress: {
      max: 100,
      curr: 50,
    },
  });
}
const stop = async()=>{
 ReactNativeForegroundService.stop();
 


So I need let the users to turn off the foreground service without entering the app and pressing the stop service button, but just by pressing the notification itself.

use this package https://notifee.app/react-native/docs/overview

@Ajith its good but in that it seems i cannot start and stop the foreground serivces as per my wish.  if i am wrong kindly let me know.  Cuz we registering the foreground service at the beginning (index.js).  So its makes me unable to start and stop and at later part of my codes
